# How to search a class in Java Library using Netbean IDE?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have no idea, but would like to know whether it is possible or not to search in java libraray using netbean IDE. For example, I have heard ArrayList. And I want to find which package ArrayList belongs to. Is there any tool or plugins to search within Java Library for Netbean IDE?

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

This shortcut triggers an action called interchangeably by the NetBeans documentation for `Go to Type...` and `Go to type/file`. The usage of this shortcut resembles the keyboard shortcut <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in Eclipse. Both IDE:s will search for a Java type/class as you type in the opened search field and provides a quick way to navigate to different types and classes. Thus in your case, instead of having to write down "ArrayList x;" in your code somewhere and hold down <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while you click on the variable type with your mouse (or any other "hack" provided in this thread now or in the future) just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and type in "arraylis" should be enough.

The shortcut may be changed if you go to your **Tools** menu item and then click **Options**. A window will pop up. Click on **Keymap** and find the action. Edit the shortcut.

You can find keyboard shortcut cards for different versions of Netbeans [here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/Keyboard_Shortcuts).

Answer (score 1):

Just type `ArrayList` + `CTRL + SPACE` Netbeans will suggest which package it belongs

But If that class isn't in classpath netbeans will suggest to create a new class with name `ArrayList`

[image]

for second of your question
[image]

Comment: Thank you!! More Question: Is it possible to search in library like we do in google? For example: It should give everything like method, return type, ..... about array if I search with keyword array. It will be like looking in documentation, but getting exactly what we want.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do that.

Just create an object for this class and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>. It will automatically import all the necessary classes. Hence you can check the package in the import statements.

Comment: Thank you  for your answer. Sorry about not making my point clear. My interest is actually about searching through library without knowing about it precisely. For example, I want to parse XML document. So, rather than going to google to find out related classes, methods, or anything else; I would like to use my own IDE to search it. So, I need some plugin || tool in Netbean which looks up library even if I do give keyword 'parse xml' rather than being more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can press ctrl and then move mouse over the function and click.
You will move to the file where that function defination is provided.
So you can easily see return type .. parameter type

To search Library .. In netbean at the top right corner serach box is given.
There you can search library like google.